# FINGERPRINT_ERROR_CANCELED

Tags: android, kotlin, fingerprint

При выключении телефона/эммулятора и повторном заходе в приложении, которое запрашивает скан отпечатка пальца, в методе `onAuthenticationError()` получаю `errorCode` == 5(ошибка приходит до метода `onPause()`).

Нашёл разбор данной проблемы [здесь](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37096471), но всё таки решение как просто игнорировать ошибку мне не совсем подходит.

Возможно получится найти какое то более оптимальное решение для данной проблемы.

На данный момент в появившемся диалоге отпечатка пальцев в методе `onResume()` у меня происходит нечто следующее:

```
fun onDialogResume() {
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && isFingerprintAuthAvailable()
                && cryptoObject != null) {
            fingerprintManager = FenturyApplication.context?.getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE) as? FingerprintManager
            mCancellationSignal = CancellationSignal()
            isDialogVisible = true
            fingerprintManager?.authenticate(cryptoObject, mCancellationSignal, 0 /* flags */,
                    authenticationCallBack, null)
        }
    } catch (e: SecurityException) {
        e.log()
    }
}
```

После чего в методе `onPause()` я так раз таки отменяю скан отпечатка пальцев и меняю сам флаг, но ошибка по-прежнему приходит.

Код метода `onPause()`:

```
fun onDialogPause() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        isDialogVisible = false
        mCancellationSignal?.cancel()
    }
}
```